# Rails Upload a File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encode

I'm using rails 3.2.13, and i need to upload a file manually (not using paperclip) and then convert it base 64.

The problem i have is that i think my file is not uploaded completly.

I am trying to upload a jpg.

Here is the code : the form

```
= form_tag send_kyc_docs_bookings_path , :multipart => true do 
              = file_field_tag :kyc_doc
              = submit_tag "Submit"
```

My controller

```
@encoded_file = Base64.encode64(File.open(params[:kyc_doc].tempfile,"r").read)
```

What i get is 
"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAtAC0AAD/4R5kRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAQAA8BAgAG\nAAAAzgAAABABAgAVAAAA1AAAABIBAwABAAAAAQAAAA==\n"

Now if i go on http://www.base64-image.de/step-2.php

I upload my file and get a string beginning like mine above but 1000 times longer.

So i came to the point that my file was not uploaded completly and here is my question:
how can i upload it completly?

Just for you to underqtand if i do

```
File.open(params[:kyc_doc].tempfile,"r").read
```

i get

"\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE0\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000\xB4\u0000\xB4\u0000\u0000\xFF\xE1\u001EdExif\u0000\u0000II*\u0000\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0010\u0000\u000F\u0001\u0002\u0000\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000\xCE\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0010\u0001\u0002\u0000\u0015\u0000\u0000\u0000\xD4\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0012\u0001\u0003\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000"

Now if i do

```
params[:kyc_doc].tempfile.read
```

i get 
"\xFF\xD8\xFF\xE0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00\xB4\x00\xB4\x00\x00\xFF\xE1\x1EdExif\x00\x00II*\x00\b\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x0F\x01\x02\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\xCE\x00\x00\x00\x10\x01\x02\x00\x15\x00\x00\x00\xD4\x00\x00\x00\x12\x01\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x1A\x01\x05\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xEA\x00\x00\x00\e\x01\x05\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xF2\x00\x00\x00(\x01\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x002\x01\x02\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\xFA\x00\x00\x00\x13\x02\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x10\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\b\x00\x00\x02\x10\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00i\x87\x04\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x16\x01\x00\x00\x01\xA4\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\xA4\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xA4\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\xA4\x05\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0E\x01\x00\x00\x06\xA4\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xBC\x03\x00\x00Canon\x00Canon PowerShot A610\x00\x00\xB4\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xB4\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x002009:03:18 16:30:39\x00 \n\x00\x00 .... (1000 times longer)

however doing

```
Base64.encode64(params[:kyc_doc].tempfile.read)
```

return an empty string

***Update :***

```
File.open(params[:kyc_doc].tempfile,"r").size
=> 241202
>> File.open(params[:kyc_doc].tempfile,"r").read.size
=> 76
```

has anyone an idea on the subject?

Thanks

***ANSWER***

Ok so i figured it out, in fact when you do

```
File.open(params[:kyc_doc].tempfile,"r")
```

It only see the first caracteres of the file (maybe because of the buffer size?)
so you need to iterate through the all sets of caracteres containing in the doc by doing

```
File.open(params[:kyc_doc].tempfile, "rb") {|io| io.read}
```

this will output all the document content

and now you can properly encode it

> @encoded_file =
>   Base64.encode64(File.open(params[:kyc_doc].tempfile,"rb") {|io|
>   io.read})

If anyone can explain it better, i would be glad to hear it ^^

Comment: Any reason you're doing this over using Paperclip or another ActiveRecord-based system?

Comment: in fact i don't need to save these files, i just need to read them, encode them then send them to an API, so i don't think i need paperclip or another system?

Comment: Nope you don't, I just wanted to check!

Comment: Ok cool, do you have an idea for my problem?

Comment: Not with the encoding stuff sorry. I can give you some ideas with Paperclip & transferring the URL to the API, but I don't think you'd benefit from it. Can you tell me why you're sending the encoded image through the API? It seems suuuuuuper inefficient to me

Comment: well it's because they want us to do it to identify our customer with some official papers like ID card, address proof ect... because it's a payment gateway and it needs to fight against fraud, laundery money ...

Comment: Okay so you're trying to send an image over an API? Why don't you just upload to your server & send the image URL?

Comment: I know it can seems weird but their doc are very clear about the fact that we need to send the images with a string (base encoded 64) :p

Comment: Wow this is weird. Can you share the API URL? I'd like to ask how much they're paying for processing power

Comment: http://docs.mangopay.com/api-references/kyc/pages/

Comment: Wow crazy - I wish you the best of luck :) Thanks for the link